# In Android I'm trying to get an image from my gallery and convert it to base64, but the file path is a null reference

Tags: android, base64, filepath, android-gallery

Here is my activity where this is happening in:

```
package com.example.alexlevine.guestify;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    TextView t3;
    Button chooseImg, uploadImg;
    ImageView imgView;
    int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    Uri filePath;
    String path;
    String encodedString;

   // private FirebaseUser user;
    private FirebaseAuth fbAuth;
    /*private TextView textViewUserEmail;

    private Button buttonLogout;

    private DatabaseReference dbRef;*/

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    public static String b64;
    /**
     * message : enrollment processed successfully
     * data : {"enrollment_id":"ahBzfmNodWlzcGRldGVjdG9ychcLEgpFbnJvbGxtZW50GICAgID5r4YKDA"}
     * success : true
     */

    private String message;
    //private DataBean data;
    private boolean success;

    //FirebaseDatabase storage = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    public ProfileActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        b64 = null;

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        setNavigationViewListner();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        chooseImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chooseImg);
        uploadImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadImg);
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        chooseImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        EnrollImg ei = new EnrollImg();

        new EnrollImg().execute();

        String r = EnrollImg.resulttouse;

        //t3.setText(r);

        Gson gson = new Gson();

       // DataBean db = gson.fromJson(r, DataBean.class);

        //String enrollid = db.getEnrollment_id();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            try {
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                path = getPath(imageUri);

                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                //Toast.makeText(PersonalDetails.this,imagepath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                b64 = BitMapToString(selectedImage);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }

    private void saveUserInformation() {
        //FirebaseUser user = fbAuth.getCurrentUser();
        //dbRef.child(user.getUid()).setValue("exp");
    }

    private void setNavigationViewListner() {
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navdrawer);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_account: {
                break;
            }
            case R.id.create: {
                break;
            }
            case R.id.org_manage: {
                break;
            }
            case R.id.join: {
                break;
            }
            case R.id.history: {
                break;
            }
            case R.id.logout: {
                fbAuth.signOut();
                finish();;
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return temp;
    }

    String encodeImage(Bitmap bitmap) {

        BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 3;

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload
        // easy
        try {

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        }

        //System.out.println("SIZE OF BITMAP " + sizeOf(bitmap));

        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        // Encode Image to String

        try {
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }


        return encodedString;

    }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
08-20 21:24:53.147 26753-26753/com.example.alexlevine.guestify 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.alexlevine.guestify, PID: 26753

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, 
request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { 
dat=content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc=1;doc=1715 
flg=0x1 }} to activity 
{com.example.alexlevine.guestify/com.example.alexlevine.guestify.
ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a 
null object reference

at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4323)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4366)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null 
object reference

at com.example.alexlevine.guestify.ProfileActivity.onActivityResult
(ProfileActivity.java:143)

at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7237)

at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4319)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4366) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649) 

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
08-20 21:24:53.147 26753-26753/com.example.alexlevine.guestify 
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result 
ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { 
dat=content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc=1;doc=1715 
flg=0x1 }} to activity 
{com.example.alexlevine.guestify/com.example.alexlevine.guestify.
ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a 
null object reference

at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4323)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4366)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null 
object reference

at com.example.alexlevine.guestify.ProfileActivity.onActivityResult
(ProfileActivity.java:143)

at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7237)

at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4319)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4366) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649) 

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I looked at several online forums and tried many variations of the methods I'm using to get and convert the images and nothing seems to be working. I'm also not sure if the null has to do with the image I'm testing in specific or my code; probably the code because it has errors even on the homepage.
Could someone please take a look at this? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your TextView.It throws NullPointerException for your TextView not for image related code. First initialize your textview then try to setText into it.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at

> {com.example.alexlevine.guestify/com.example.alexlevine.guestify.
>   ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual  method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

I think the error is unrelated to the image, but the text view is null instead when you set the text to it.